# Adding output types to multiple sales orders, purchase orders, delivery or invoice

Tags: abap

Can anyone tell me how to use `RV_MESSAGE_INSERT` and `RV_MESSAGE_UPDATE` function modules to insert output types to multiple orders, deliveries or quotations at a single time?

How can this be achieved? If I am using select-options as an input to get OBJKY (NAST table), how to achieve that? Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

One warning before using `RV_MESSAGES_INSERT` and `RV_MESSAGES_UPDATE`: You will be able to see the output messages only in display mode (VA03, VL03N, VF03, etc).

The field NAST-KAPPL controls the Application Area in which you're storing a particular message. So `NAST-KAPPL = 'V1'` is Sales, similarly `V2` is Shipping, `V3` is billing (You can check all the possible values in transaction `NACE`).

The other fields are pretty self-explanatory. If you would like to store a message for a delivery, your code would look something like this:

```
DATA(message_record) = VALUE NAST( KAPPL = 'V2'
                                   OBJKY = delivery-vbeln "Delivery
                                   MANDT = SY-MANDT "Client
                                   KSCHL = 'ZD10' "Message type
                                   SPRAS = sy-langu "Language
                                   PARNR = delivery-kunnr "message partner
                                   PARVW = 'SH' "Ship-to-party partner function
                                   ERDAT = sy-datum 
                                   ERUHR = sy-uzeit
                                   NACHA = '8' "Message transmission medium. Check domain values
                                   VSTYP = '4' "Send immediately. Check domain values
                                   MANUE = 'X' ). "Very important: message processed manually

APPEND message_record TO message_table. "message_table is type NAST

CALL FUNCTION ‘RV_MESSAGES_INSERT‘
TABLES
tab_xnast = message_table.

CALL FUNCTION ‘RV_MESSAGES_UPDATE‘
EXPORTING
msg_kappl = message_record-kappl
msg_objky = message_record-objky.

COMMIT WORK.
```

If you wanna do this with multiple orders/deliveries, just put everything inside a `LOOP`, refreshing `message_table` at the beginning of the loop.